# From JSON to Actionscript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good Day,
is it possible to convert an object to an Actioscript model in Javascript ? 
I have this:

```
const user = [{"id":"1","name":"Doe","firstname":"John","tel":"1112223333"}];
```

I would like to have this:

```
const user = [{id:1,name:"Doe",firstname:"John",tel:1112223333}];
```

When I use `user.replace(/"/g,"");` I have the error:

> user.replace is not a function

But this is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to do it if I can't use `replace`.
To put you in context, the object is fetched via ajax and PHP by doing `echo json_encode($to_encode);`
Thank You for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipt-_ZuuDUAhXFMo8KHZ87AHEQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AFQjCNHkowMNeO8CgweprUJz3xDY9HxuPQ)

**Updated**

convert the string to number

```js
const user ='[{"id":"1","name":"Doe","firstname":"John","tel":"1112223333"}]';
var res  =JSON.parse(user)

res.forEach(function(a){ //convert the string to number
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key){
  a[key] = Number(a[key])||a[key]
})
})
console.log(res)
```

Check you broswer console.log `F12` is showen like this

[image]

Comment: well, const user in the question is already an object :p also, he seems to want to convert numeric strings to Numbers as if by some majicks :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I see .. op  mentioned  return the data from php `echo json_encode($to_encode);`  .Its only a json string not  with direct json Object .Op was missing quotes of json string

Comment: I tried JSON.parse() but it doesn't change the format of the data. In my case, I need to remove the quotes around numerical values and the name attributes.

Comment: It might work, but for some reason I have a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`... on line `var res = JSON.parse(user)`. I'm trying to elude this mistery...

Comment: @EricF ok remove the json.parse .try direct with `user` instead `res`

Comment: Ok, this solution worked ! I used `user.forEach...`. For this question, I used a common example for the data. But my real content has more data in it. For some reasons, it worked with many numerical data but not all (like float for example, but also some int didn't work too)... Any idea why ?

Comment: Also, I'd like a bit of explanations here... Not sure I understand the solution... :-/

Comment: Well, you just made my day prasad!! Thanks a lot for your help! :)